# How do I change my iCloud email?

Tags: icloud, email

I don't even know where to begin with this, but a while back I tried getting apple music and it worked, but I somehow messed up my iCloud because I changed my email. My iCloud on my iPhone has my new email, but I can't change it on my mac, and it says my password is wrong when I type it in to my old email for my iCloud. So now I can't use my laptop without something from my iCloud system preferences popping up telling me something's wrong.

Comment: Just to confirm, you're interested in only using your new iCloud email address for both devices, not the old one ?

Comment: Have you checked this [link](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204071)? Seems like updating your email address is different on Macs